# PHP - Using Cron Jobs and GD together

Tags: php, performance, cron, gd

I have a customer based website which requires them to upload an image, and on doing so my script will save about 25-30 variations of the image onto the server using the GD library. Because of the amount of images there is currently a very long waiting time for the customer to continue on the site waiting until all images have been created and saved. Until then they cannot proceed so we get a high level of customers leaving the site.

Is it possible after upload to instead store the image url in a database table record, then have a php script which creates the 25-30 images pull each record in the database and run every 5 minutes of the day using cronjob. This way it allows the customer to continue through the website and have the images automatically created 'in the background'

Will all this going on in the background cause any issues for the speed of my site? Will it slowdown the site for people browsing especially if 10-100's of customers are using it at the same time?

Comment: yes you can do this, depending on what you are actually doing to the images you may want to look at running `jpegtran` which will result in images that are optimized better then what GD can do.

Comment: Open the file `/etc/cron.d/image_processing` and put in `0-55/5 * * * * www-data /path/to/usr/bin/php /path/to/script`, assuming your webservers user is www-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a PHP script process the images would cause no more lag in a cron job than it would when the customer uploads the image and waits for the processing to complete in realtime. So in short, no there's no **additional** impact of this approach.

The catch is, you need to make sure your cron job is self-aware and does not create overlaps. For example if the cron runs and takes more than 5 minutes to complete its current task, what happens when a second cron spins up and begins processing another image (or the same one if you didn't implement the queue properly)? Well now you have two crons running, fighting for resources. Which means the second one will likely take over 5 minutes as well. Eventually you get to the point with 3, 4, etc crons all running at once. So make sure your crons are only "booting up" if there's not one running already.

All this being said, you'd probably be best off having another server handle the image processing depending on the size of your client's site and how heavy their traffic is. You could have a cloud server in a cluster with your production site server which can connect via local network to access an image, process it, and return the 25-30 copies to the server in the appropriate location. This way your processing queue occupies 0 resources of the public facing web server and will have no impact on speed of the site itself.

Comment: Have you got any articles/tutorials on how i may set this up? I have not heard or seen of multiple servers for one site so wouldn't know where to start!

Comment: Implementing a multi-server setup would be the more advanced of the two options there as it would require networking the two filesystems together so that the processing server could read/write to the web-facing server. I would start with a simple system of building the cron job so that it doesn't allow overlapping runs, etc and having it process in the background. From there you can easily expand later.

Comment: Thanks Brian, i'm now going down this route and using flock() to make sure there are no overlaps

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start looking at [queues](http://queues.io/), more specific to [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

This will decrease the load time for your customers as you can offload the generation of the images to a separate server. And it scales easily across multiple servers if you need more processing power.

Comment: Unfortunately the current shared server won't allow gearman and the client will not upgrade or change. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use an external queue, like IronMQ or Amazon Simple Queue Service. But then again if your customer don't want to upgrade I think he doesn't want to pay either for these external services ...

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can store PATH of an image on your server and process it later.
create php script that when run creates a LOCK file ie "/tmp/imgprocessor.lock" and deletes it at the end, if cron starts a new process you first check that file doesn't exist.
I would store uploaded images in ie pathtoimages/toprocess/  and delete each one after processing or move it elsewhere. Have new images in ie /processed/

This way you don't need to query DB for path of images but just process what is in 'toprocess' folder and you can just have UNIQ_NAME_OF_IMAGE in table. In your web script before loading the oage check if UNIQ_NAME_OF_IMAGE exist in 'processed' folder , and if so display it ...

On server load , it depends how many images you originaly have and what sizes are, image processing can be heavy on server but processing 1000 users *30 images wont be a heavy duty task , as I said depends on size of images.

NOTE: if you go this way you need to make sure that when starting a cron ERROR log is also outputed to some log file. Cron script must be bullet proof ie if it fails for some reason LOCK file will remain , so no more processing will happen , you will need to delete it manually (or create custom error handler that deletes it and maybe send some mails ) , you should check periodically log file so you know whats going on.